# How to detect system information like os or device type

Tags: android, logging, properties, debugging

The most important things I want to know are the device type, the OS version, if it has a hardware keyboard and maybe the screen resolution. but if you know other useful debug information please add them :)

I found this for the OS version:

```
string += "OS Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version");
```

How do I get the other properties?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

edit: to get a complete overview of useful attributes, I combined them all together in my ErrorHandler activity (start to read at line 56): https://github.com/simon-heinen/SimpleUi/blob/master/SimpleUI/srcAndroid/simpleui/util/DeviceInformation.java#L56

Windowsize and keyboard presence were a good idea, i added some more infos for debug purpose:

```
String s="Debug-infos:";
s += "\n OS Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version") + "(" + android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + ")";
s += "\n OS API Level: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
s += "\n Device: " + android.os.Build.DEVICE;
s += "\n Model (and Product): " + android.os.Build.MODEL + " ("+ android.os.Build.PRODUCT + ")";
```

Comment: Here is an [updated link](https://github.com/simon-heinen/SimpleUi/blob/master/SimpleUI/srcAndroid/simpleui/util/DeviceInformation.java).

Comment: This will require `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` and `SystemUtil.isGlass` is not available

Comment: I improved it by using `StringBuilder` for concatenating `String` to get faster runtime, add null checkings to avoid force closed, change implementation to get app info using `BuildConfig` to make sure the availability, removed `SystemUtil.isGlass`, and other minor improvements. Here is the updated link https://gist.github.com/hendrawd/01f215fd332d84793e600e7f82fc154b

Comment: How can I find the SDK level?

Answer (score 32):

Here is all device informations that is possible in android using below enum and utility class

```
public enum Device {
        DEVICE_TYPE, DEVICE_SYSTEM_NAME, DEVICE_VERSION, DEVICE_SYSTEM_VERSION, DEVICE_TOKEN,
        /**
         *
         */
        DEVICE_NAME, DEVICE_UUID, DEVICE_MANUFACTURE, IPHONE_TYPE,
        /**
         *
         */
        CONTACT_ID, DEVICE_LANGUAGE, DEVICE_TIME_ZONE, DEVICE_LOCAL_COUNTRY_CODE,
        /**
         *
         */
        DEVICE_CURRENT_YEAR, DEVICE_CURRENT_DATE_TIME, DEVICE_CURRENT_DATE_TIME_ZERO_GMT,
        /**
         *
         */
        DEVICE_HARDWARE_MODEL, DEVICE_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, DEVICE_LOCALE, DEVICE_NETWORK, DEVICE_NETWORK_TYPE,
        /**
         *
         */
        DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS_IPV4, DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS_IPV6, DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS, DEVICE_TOTAL_CPU_USAGE,
        /**
         *
         */
        DEVICE_TOTAL_MEMORY, DEVICE_FREE_MEMORY, DEVICE_USED_MEMORY,
        /**
         *
         */
        DEVICE_TOTAL_CPU_USAGE_USER, DEVICE_TOTAL_CPU_USAGE_SYSTEM,
        /**
         *
         */
        DEVICE_TOTAL_CPU_IDLE, DEVICE_IN_INCH;
    }
```

--> Utility class :

```
 public class DeviceInfo {

        public static String getDeviceInfo(Context activity, Device device) {
            try {
                switch (device) {
                    case DEVICE_LANGUAGE:
                        return Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
                    case DEVICE_TIME_ZONE:
                        return TimeZone.getDefault().getID();//(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
                    case DEVICE_LOCAL_COUNTRY_CODE:
                        return activity.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
                    case DEVICE_CURRENT_YEAR:
                        return "" + (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
                    case DEVICE_CURRENT_DATE_TIME:
                        Calendar calendarTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
                        long time = (calendarTime.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
                        return String.valueOf(time);
    //                    return DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                    case DEVICE_CURRENT_DATE_TIME_ZERO_GMT:
                        Calendar calendarTime_zero = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"), Locale.getDefault());
                        return String.valueOf((calendarTime_zero.getTimeInMillis() / 1000));
    //                    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    //                    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));
    //                    return df.format(new Date());
                    case DEVICE_HARDWARE_MODEL:
                        return getDeviceName();
                    case DEVICE_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS:
                        return Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + "";
                    case DEVICE_LOCALE:
                        return Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country();
                    case DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS_IPV4:
                        return getIPAddress(true);
                    case DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS_IPV6:
                        return getIPAddress(false);
                    case DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS:
                        String mac = getMACAddress("wlan0");
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mac)) {
                            mac = getMACAddress("eth0");
                        }
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mac)) {
                            mac = "DU:MM:YA:DD:RE:SS";
                        }
                        return mac;

                    case DEVICE_TOTAL_MEMORY:
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
                            return String.valueOf(getTotalMemory(activity));
                    case DEVICE_FREE_MEMORY:
                        return String.valueOf(getFreeMemory(activity));
                    case DEVICE_USED_MEMORY:
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                            long freeMem = getTotalMemory(activity) - getFreeMemory(activity);
                            return String.valueOf(freeMem);
                        }
                        return "";
                    case DEVICE_TOTAL_CPU_USAGE:
                        int[] cpu = getCpuUsageStatistic();
                        if (cpu != null) {
                            int total = cpu[0] + cpu[1] + cpu[2] + cpu[3];
                            return String.valueOf(total);
                        }
                        return "";
                    case DEVICE_TOTAL_CPU_USAGE_SYSTEM:
                        int[] cpu_sys = getCpuUsageStatistic();
                        if (cpu_sys != null) {
                            int total = cpu_sys[1];
                            return String.valueOf(total);
                        }
                        return "";
                    case DEVICE_TOTAL_CPU_USAGE_USER:
                        int[] cpu_usage = getCpuUsageStatistic();
                        if (cpu_usage != null) {
                            int total = cpu_usage[0];
                            return String.valueOf(total);
                        }
                        return "";
                    case DEVICE_MANUFACTURE:
                        return android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
                    case DEVICE_SYSTEM_VERSION:
                        return String.valueOf(getDeviceName());
                    case DEVICE_VERSION:
                        return String.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
                    case DEVICE_IN_INCH:
                        return getDeviceInch(activity);
                    case DEVICE_TOTAL_CPU_IDLE:
                        int[] cpu_idle = getCpuUsageStatistic();
                        if (cpu_idle != null) {
                            int total = cpu_idle[2];
                            return String.valueOf(total);
                        }
                        return "";
                    case DEVICE_NETWORK_TYPE:
                        return getNetworkType(activity);
                    case DEVICE_NETWORK:
                        return checkNetworkStatus(activity);
                    case DEVICE_TYPE:
                        if (isTablet(activity)) {
                            if (getDeviceMoreThan5Inch(activity)) {
                                return "Tablet";
                            } else
                                return "Mobile";
                        } else {
                            return "Mobile";
                        }
                    case DEVICE_SYSTEM_NAME:
                        return "Android OS";
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }

        public static String getDeviceId(Context context) {
            String device_uuid = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            if (device_uuid == null) {
                device_uuid = "12356789"; // for emulator testing
            } else {
                try {
                    byte[] _data = device_uuid.getBytes();
                    MessageDigest _digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                    _digest.update(_data);
                    _data = _digest.digest();
                    BigInteger _bi = new BigInteger(_data).abs();
                    device_uuid = _bi.toString(36);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return device_uuid;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private static long getTotalMemory(Context activity) {
            try {
                MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
                ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
                long availableMegs = mi.totalMem / 1048576L; // in megabyte (mb)

                return availableMegs;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            }
        }

        private static long getFreeMemory(Context activity) {
            try {
                MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
                ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
                long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L; // in megabyte (mb)

                return availableMegs;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            }
        }

        private static String getDeviceName() {
            String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
            String model = Build.MODEL;
            if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
                return capitalize(model);
            } else {
                return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
            }
        }

        private static String capitalize(String s) {
            if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
                return "";
            }
            char first = s.charAt(0);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) {
                return s;
            } else {
                return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Convert byte array to hex string
         *
         * @param bytes
         * @return
         */
        private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
            StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
            for (int idx = 0; idx < bytes.length; idx++) {
                int intVal = bytes[idx] & 0xff;
                if (intVal < 0x10)
                    sbuf.append("0");
                sbuf.append(Integer.toHexString(intVal).toUpperCase());
            }
            return sbuf.toString();
        }

        /**
         * Returns MAC address of the given interface name.
         *
         * @param interfaceName eth0, wlan0 or NULL=use first interface
         * @return mac address or empty string
         */
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private static String getMACAddress(String interfaceName) {
            try {

                List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
                for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
                    if (interfaceName != null) {
                        if (!intf.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(interfaceName))
                            continue;
                    }
                    byte[] mac = intf.getHardwareAddress();
                    if (mac == null)
                        return "";
                    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < mac.length; idx++)
                        buf.append(String.format("%02X:", mac[idx]));
                    if (buf.length() > 0)
                        buf.deleteCharAt(buf.length() - 1);
                    return buf.toString();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return "";
            } // for now eat exceptions
            return "";
            /*
             * try { // this is so Linux hack return
             * loadFileAsString("/sys/class/net/" +interfaceName +
             * "/address").toUpperCase().trim(); } catch (IOException ex) { return
             * null; }
             */
        }

        /**
         * Get IP address from first non-localhost interface
         *
         * @return address or empty string
         */
        private static String getIPAddress(boolean useIPv4) {
            try {
                List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
                for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
                    List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
                    for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                        if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                            String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress().toUpperCase();
                            boolean isIPv4 = InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(sAddr);
                            if (useIPv4) {
                                if (isIPv4)
                                    return sAddr;
                            } else {
                                if (!isIPv4) {
                                    int delim = sAddr.indexOf('%'); // drop ip6 port
                                    // suffix
                                    return delim < 0 ? sAddr : sAddr.substring(0, delim);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            } // for now eat exceptions
            return "";
        }

        /*
         *
         * @return integer Array with 4 elements: user, system, idle and other cpu
         * usage in percentage.
         */
        private static int[] getCpuUsageStatistic() {
            try {
                String tempString = executeTop();

                tempString = tempString.replaceAll(",", "");
                tempString = tempString.replaceAll("User", "");
                tempString = tempString.replaceAll("System", "");
                tempString = tempString.replaceAll("IOW", "");
                tempString = tempString.replaceAll("IRQ", "");
                tempString = tempString.replaceAll("%", "");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    tempString = tempString.replaceAll("  ", " ");
                }
                tempString = tempString.trim();
                String[] myString = tempString.split(" ");
                int[] cpuUsageAsInt = new int[myString.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
                    myString[i] = myString[i].trim();
                    cpuUsageAsInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(myString[i]);
                }
                return cpuUsageAsInt;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("executeTop", "error in getting cpu statics");
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static String executeTop() {
            java.lang.Process p = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;
            String returnString = null;
            try {
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n 1");
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                while (returnString == null || returnString.contentEquals("")) {
                    returnString = in.readLine();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("executeTop", "error in getting first line of top");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    in.close();
                    p.destroy();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("executeTop", "error in closing and destroying top process");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return returnString;
        }

        public static String getNetworkType(final Context activity) {
            String networkStatus = "";

            final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                    activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            // check for wifi
            final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
                    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            // check for mobile data
            final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =
                    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            if (wifi.isAvailable()) {
                networkStatus = "Wifi";
            } else if (mobile.isAvailable()) {
                networkStatus = getDataType(activity);
            } else {
                networkStatus = "noNetwork";
            }
            return networkStatus;
        }

        public static String checkNetworkStatus(final Context activity) {
            String networkStatus = "";
            try {
                // Get connect mangaer
                final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                // // check for wifi
                final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
                connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                // // check for mobile data
                final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =
                connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

                if (wifi.isAvailable()) {
                networkStatus = "Wifi";
                } else if (mobile.isAvailable()) {
                networkStatus = getDataType(activity);
                } else {
                networkStatus = "noNetwork";
                networkStatus = "0";
               }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                networkStatus = "0";
            }
            return networkStatus;

        } 

 public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
    }

    public static boolean getDeviceMoreThan5Inch(Context activity) {
        try {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            // int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            // int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

            float yInches = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.ydpi;
            float xInches = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.xdpi;
            double diagonalInches = Math.sqrt(xInches * xInches + yInches * yInches);
            if (diagonalInches >= 7) {
                // 5inch device or bigger
                return true;
            } else {
                // smaller device
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String getDeviceInch(Context activity) {
        try {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

            float yInches = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.ydpi;
            float xInches = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.xdpi;
            double diagonalInches = Math.sqrt(xInches * xInches + yInches * yInches);
            return String.valueOf(diagonalInches);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "-1";
        }
    }

    public static String getDataType(Context activity) {
        String type = "Mobile Data";
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        switch (tm.getNetworkType()) {
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                type = "Mobile Data 3G";
                Log.d("Type", "3g");
                // for 3g HSDPA networktype will be return as
                // per testing(real) in device with 3g enable
                // data
                // and speed will also matters to decide 3g network type
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
                type = "Mobile Data 4G";
                Log.d("Type", "4g");
                // No specification for the 4g but from wiki
                // i found(HSPAP used in 4g)
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                type = "Mobile Data GPRS";
                Log.d("Type", "GPRS");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                type = "Mobile Data EDGE 2G";
                Log.d("Type", "EDGE 2g");
                break;

        }

        return type;
        }
}
```

-- Get IP Address without using InetAddressUtils class

```
    private static final String IPV4_BASIC_PATTERN_STRING =
                "(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}" + // initial 3 fields, 0-255 followed by .
                        "([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"; // final field, 0-255
    private static final Pattern IPV4_PATTERN =
                Pattern.compile("^" + IPV4_BASIC_PATTERN_STRING + "$");
    public static boolean isIPv4Address(final String input) {
            return IPV4_PATTERN.matcher(input).matches();
   }

   /**
     * Get IP address from first non-localhost interface
     *
     * @return address or empty string
     */
    private static String getIPAddress(boolean useIPv4) {
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
                List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
                for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                    if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress().toUpperCase();
                        //TODO 3.0.0
                        boolean isIPv4 = isIPv4Address(sAddr);
                        if (useIPv4) {
                            if (isIPv4)
                                return sAddr;
                        } else {
                            if (!isIPv4) {
                                int delim = sAddr.indexOf('%'); // drop ip6 port
                                // suffix
                                return delim < 0 ? sAddr : sAddr.substring(0, delim);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } // for now eat exceptions
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: `DEVICE_SYSTEM_NAME` is not handled.

Comment: @ThomasW : Add  `case DEVICE_SYSTEM_NAME: return "Android OS";` for DEVICE_SYSTEM_NAME

Comment: @Maveň : Please see my updated answer for getIPAddress method.

Comment: Instead of `boolean isIPv4 = InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(sAddr);` you can use `boolean isIPv4 = addr instanceof Inet4Address;`

Answer (score 10):

For screen resolution:

```
getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

For hardware keyboard presence:

```
boolean keyboardPresent = (getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard != Configuration.KEYBOARD_NOKEYS);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can try this >

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.Settings;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Utilies {


    public static String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(App.getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    public static void getInternet() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    public static String readKernelVersion() {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uname -a");
            InputStream is = null;
            if (p.waitFor() == 0) {
                is = p.getInputStream();
            } else {
                is = p.getErrorStream();
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 1024);
            String line = br.readLine();
            br.close();
            return line;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
        }
    }


    public static String getDeviceModelNumber() {
        String manufacturer = Build.VERSION.CODENAME;
        String model = Build.MODEL;
        if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
            return capitalize(model);
        } else {
            return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
        }
    }

    private static  String capitalize(String s) {
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        char first = s.charAt(0);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) {
            return s;
        } else {
            return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
        }
    }
    // get System info.
    public static String OSNAME = System.getProperty("os.name");
    public static String OSVERSION = System.getProperty("os.version");
    public static String RELEASE = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    public static String DEVICE = android.os.Build.DEVICE;
    public static String MODEL = android.os.Build.MODEL;
    public static String PRODUCT = android.os.Build.PRODUCT;
    public static String BRAND = android.os.Build.BRAND;
    public static String DISPLAY = android.os.Build.DISPLAY;
    public static String CPU_ABI = android.os.Build.CPU_ABI;
    public static String CPU_ABI2 = android.os.Build.CPU_ABI2;
    public static String UNKNOWN = android.os.Build.UNKNOWN;
    public static String HARDWARE = android.os.Build.HARDWARE;
    public static String ID = android.os.Build.ID;
    public static String MANUFACTURER = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    public static String SERIAL = android.os.Build.SERIAL;
    public static String USER = android.os.Build.USER;
    public static String HOST = android.os.Build.HOST;


}
```

Comment: `os.version` property returns the Linux/Kernel version, so no need to use that `readKernelVersion()` method...

Answer (score 1):

Update on screen resolution:
getHeight() and getWidth deprecated in API level 13 - HONEYCOMB_MR2; use getSize(Point) instead.
More info at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get Device Information.

```
String serviceType = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
TelephonyManager m_telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService(serviceType);
String DeviceId, SubscriberId, NetworkOperator, OsVersion,SimOperatorName;
DeviceId = m_telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
SubscriberId = m_telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
NetworkOperator = m_telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
OsVersion = m_telephonyManager.getDeviceSoftwareVersion();
SimOperatorName = m_telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
```

Show Output

```
Log.d("Device Information :", "\n DeviceId : " + DeviceId +
                            "\n SubscriberId : " + SubscriberId
                            + "\n NetworkOperator : " + NetworkOperator +
                            "\n SoftwareVersion : " + OsVersion+
                            "\n SimOperatorName : " + SimOperatorName);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Log.i(TAG, "Device Info: " + System.getProperty("http.agent"));
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the OP's question about device/system type

Comment: It does print the device/system type. For me, I got the following:
*Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; Lenovo A7010a48 Build/LMY47D)*
What output did you get?