# Developing an universal android application (phone and tablet)

Tags: android

I'm developing an universal android application and I need to check if the application is running in a tablet or in a phone. Is there any method to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the [Google I/O App for Android](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) src code:

In the [UIUtils](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/UIUtils.java) class you have the following methods:

```
public static boolean isHoneycomb() {
    // Can use static final constants like HONEYCOMB, declared in later versions
    // of the OS since they are inlined at compile time. This is guaranteed behavior.
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
}

public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}

public static boolean isHoneycombTablet(Context context) {
    return isHoneycomb() && isTablet(context);
}
```

Comment: Hello Macarse, i have one question related to this topic... how can i develop Universal app that will run on phone(2.2 and later) and on tablet?

Comment: Use the compatibility package when developing your app. You can read more here [http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html]

Answer (score 0):

In the sdk you can create a device with the atributes you want (screen resolution, ram, touch screen, gps .... )

Answer (score 0):

That's actually an interesting question.
I don't have an absolute answer, but you might find some good input here [How to detect system information like os or device type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213205/how-to-detect-system-information-like-os-or-device-type)

And also, TelephonyManager.getPhoneType() and other methods in TelephonyManager might be of interest.

Use Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) to get an instance of TelephonyManager.

Comment: Macarse's answer looks promising too.

Answer (score 0):

New implementation from Google Jelly Bean:

```
 // SystemUI (status bar) layout policy
        int shortSizeDp = shortSize
                * DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT
                / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEVICE;

        if (shortSizeDp < 600) {
            // 0-599dp: "phone" UI with a separate status & navigation bar
            mHasSystemNavBar = false;
            mNavigationBarCanMove = true;
        } else if (shortSizeDp < 720) {
            // 600-719dp: "phone" UI with modifications for larger screens
            mHasSystemNavBar = false;
            mNavigationBarCanMove = false;
        } else {
            // 720dp: "tablet" UI with a single combined status & navigation bar
            mHasSystemNavBar = true;
            mNavigationBarCanMove = false;
        }
        }
```

Comment: what is `shortSize` ?