# Unknown sources settings android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-install-apk

The issue is that I need to install an apk(non market app) and for this, the user need to activate the unknown source setting, so i send him (if he didn't have it activated) to the settings so he can turn on the option, the issue is that i tested it in different phones and in samsung that option is on applications while in htcs phones is on security. i want send the user to that option  but i don't know how to do it

I read about this and no one knows exactly how to do it

this is my code

```
    int canInstallFromOtherSources = Settings.Secure.getInt(ctx2,Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS);
    if(canInstallFromOtherSources == 0)
    {
        Intent intentSettings = new Intent();                         
        intentSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS);       
        startActivity(intentSettings);              
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following line (changing to the corresponding action):

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_LOCATION_PROVIDERS);
```

Check [Android Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) documentation.

I think you should use [ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS) and one of [ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS) or [ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS).

And [here](https://github.com/barriosnahuel/tourGuide/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nbempire/android/tourguide/component/activity/MapActivity.java) (line 304), you've got a working example of one of my apps: [Tureame](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nbempire.android.tourguide)

Comment: thanks for the answer i tryied what you say  and with Action_Application_development_Settings it crash it some devices, and yes i should use the other two but, how i can know in which one is correct for the device?

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074584/android-device-information) here in SO and you can use the [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class, actually the [MANUFACTURER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MANUFACTURER) constant field. So if you know that all HTC devices have the same configuration then you can do some specific coding for that case.

Comment: I think this only allowed for rooted device only. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't know now for the newest API Levels, but in that moment that wasn't necessary. Why do you thik that? Regards!