# How to get Device Information in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect system information like os or device type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213205/how-to-detect-system-information-like-os-or-device-type)

I am new to android application development.

I developed one small application,and install that application .apk file in my device,it is working good.

But my requirement is When i install .apk file first time in my device,then i have to retrieve 
the total device information and store that information in my database.

please help me go forward

Comment: the total device information ?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What informations you want?

Comment: What information do you want?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [Build Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) to get the device information.

For example:

```
String myDeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

Answer (score 78):

You may want to take a look at those pages : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html (the *getProperty()* method might do the job).

For instance :

```
System.getProperty("os.version"); // OS version
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK      // API Level
android.os.Build.DEVICE           // Device
android.os.Build.MODEL            // Model 
android.os.Build.PRODUCT          // Product
```

Etc...

Comment: System.getProperty("os.version") returns linux version not android os version

Comment: also for even more device infos have a look at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.kibotu.android.deviceinfo it is open source on github as well

Comment: Do any of these ever return null?

Comment: SDK is deprecated, use .SDK_INT instead

Comment: Use `android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE` to get the user-friendly Android OS version (e.g. 8.1.0).

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
// Code For IMEI AND IMSI NUMBER

String serviceName = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
TelephonyManager m_telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(serviceName);
String IMEI,IMSI;
IMEI = m_telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
IMSI = m_telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want device ID information use TelephonyManager. Here is the link for that :

http://facinatingandroid.blogspot.in/2011/09/android-device-information.html

and also check this :

http://sree.cc/google/android/reading-phone-device-details-in-android

Comment: good information