# How to get device details from a mac address

Tags: java, android, networking

In my app i'm having a list of mac addresses from which i want to fetch devices details like it's operating system model number etc. i tried many solution available online but none of them seem to help however there is one mac vendors api which i tried implementing and through which i can fetch only device manufacturer name however that doesn't satisfy my application goals.
So my question is how can i programmatically get device details from an mac address or an ip address?
 This is the code i used to call mac vendors api but however i don't want to use any api in my app:

```
String macAdress = "5caafd1b0019";
String dataUrl = "http://api.macvendors.com/" + macAdress;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(dataUrl);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {response.append(line);response.append('\r');}
    rd.close();
    String responseStr = response.toString();
    Log.d("Server response", responseStr);
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} finally {if (connection != null) {connection.disconnect();}}
```

Comment: I think it will help you to get the details
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/MAC_Vendor_Lookup#Java

Comment: As far as i know you will only be able to get the vendor name from a MAC address, the first 24 bits (3 bytes) is the OUI or the name of the company that the range was assigned to. The last part is the part unique to the device, but it has nothing to do with the operating system or anything like that. An IP address also doesn't contain in it no details about the machine it was (temporarily) assigned to.

Comment: You might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819361/how-to-get-device-information-in-android

Comment: @Maxim VA That doesn't help i'm having mac address of different devices sometimes they can be of apple or any other os and hence build class won't be useful for me

Comment: Then see my first answer, from a MAC address (or IP address) you cannot get such details.