# Full CPU info (Android Developing)

Tags: cpu

If can I to get all of these CPU info?
In proc/cpuinfo shows instructions set. 
Thanks.
[Image](http://1drv.ms/1e9thTH)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213205/how-to-detect-system-information-like-os-or-device-type

Comment: Thanks, but System.getProperty("os.version") shows me kernel version only, but Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uname -a") return an [error](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F1DD18CC8E183D6C!765&authkey=!ACyFJWFyTkEp_vc&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng). I mean can I get CPU manufacturer name, core name, number of cores, manufacturing process, clock range and governor type or it is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
private String getInfo() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("abi: ").append(Build.CPU_ABI).append("\n");
    if (new File("/proc/cpuinfo").exists()) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/proc/cpuinfo")));
            String aLine;
            while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(aLine + "\n");
            }
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

[image: output]

Source for further reference: [how-to-get-cpu-information-on-android](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-get-cpu-information-on-android/)

Comment: How to get **CPU clock range** and **number of cores**?

Comment: you can get help from the existing apps like CPU-Z or [CPU Tuner](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cputuner/files/releases/)

Comment: I know abou that. I wanted to create my own "About system" app

Comment: I meant you can check the source code for these open source apps for help.

Comment: Ok. I'll see if I'm able to get something from these codes. My programming skills is on junior level.