# How to make user pay multiple times for multiple installs / AKA connect a purchased item to device instead of user

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm making an app that expects the user to pay to get its full features.

I can create two apps, one free and one premium, or as a second solution I can ask the user to pay for a registration item as in-app purchase.

The problem is, for the nature of this app, the user that buys it probably will need to install it on multiple devices, and I want him to pay for every device. In both solutions, as I can see, a user could pay for one and install multiple times.

Is there a solution for this?

Edit: as suggested, I can link the purchased item to the device instead of to the user: how can this be done?

Comment: What about rather than associating every purchase with a specific user connect the purchase with every device? Connect every device with the user but the payment/unlock not with the user but with his/her device. That's the only way I can think of now.

Comment: I'll check documentation for this smart idea, I never did anything similar.

Comment: Nevertheless I think your question is too broad. There are probably ways to solve your problem, but I don't think your question is specific enough. There could be 5 or 6 users with correct answers and none of the answers is the same.

Comment: I changed the question, asking, as suggested by you, how to connect the device instead of the user to the in-app purchase. Do you have done it already, and do you have an example to publish here, in case? Thanks.

Comment: I never did something like that, what I suggested was just an idea I had. I did search for a way to get the information from a device ( here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213205/how-to-detect-system-information-like-os-or-device-type ). What I want to add is that I really have no idea how to implement it but I just tried to think of a way to get around the user as the unique identification factor.

Comment: Maybe get the user device information, add the username to it and save it in a database? Add an attribute to the table if there was a payment or not. Any ideas how to proceed?