# I'm Creating test cases script for IOS and android mobile application

Tags: android, automation, appium

I want to implement a method to detect type of device connected and run it's specified script any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect system information like os or device type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213205/how-to-detect-system-information-like-os-or-device-type)

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of script do you want it to run?

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to help us better help you.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the device for Android and iOS. Do whatever you want to do from there.

In Android:

```
String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String model = Build.MODEL;
```

In iOS:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/8200290

Answer (score 0):

I created enum and method to differentiate between both types

```
public static OS detectOperatingSystem ()
{if (OSName.contains("android")) {
        return OS.ANDROID;
    }

    if (OSName.contains("ios")) {
        return OS.IOS;
    }
    else return null;
}

String = OSName;
public enum OS {IOS,ANDROID}

}
```

@BeforeClass
    public void  getDesiredCapabilites() throws MalformedURLException {

```
    switch (detectOperatingSystem()) {
        case ANDROID:
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, androidVirtualDeviceVersion);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, androidMobilePlatform);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, androidVirtualDeviceVersion);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, androidAutomationName);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, androidFilePath);
            capabilities.setCapability("eventTimings", true);
            //capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
            setDriver();
            break;

        case IOS:
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, IOSDeviceName);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, IOSMobilePlatform);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, IOSPlatformVersion);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, IOSAutomationName);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, IOSFilePath);
            setDriver();
            //IOSdriver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

            break;
    }
```